# How to keep different versions of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to use a different set of firebase libraries in the project. But I'm getting the following error :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0.
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
```

Comment: Why do you need to use different versions of firebase? For whatever reason, you can add different [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) for your project that use different dependencies.

Comment: @tomerpacific bcz i want to use latest versions of all libraries.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the latest versions, then you can use firebase `BoM`, in the `build.gradle`, write the following:

```
dependencies {
  // Import the platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:20.0.1')

  // When using a BoM, dependencies don't require a specified version
  // If you do specify a version, it overrides the library version specified in the BoM
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

`com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:20.0.1` will contain the latest version of all firebase libraries, then to use each specific library you add them as you normally do but without a version.

References:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#firebase-bom